# How do I connect a container to an array of objects in Vaadin?

Tags: arrays, data-binding, containers, vaadin

I'm currently working on a stats tracking app for a Software Engineering class. I have a deck object which looks like this:

```
public class Deck {

    private String name;
    private String clas;
    private int winCoin,winNoCoin,lossCoin,lossNoCoin;
    private int[][] stats;
    public Deck() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Deck(String name, String clas){
        this.name=name;
        this.clas=clas;
        winCoin=0;
        winNoCoin=0;
        lossCoin=0;
        lossNoCoin=0;
        stats=new int[9][4];
    }

    /*
     * Add Data Chart
     *  
     *          0   1   2   3
     *          WC  WNC LC  LNC
     *0 Warrior 
     *1 Shaman
     *2 Rogue
     *3 Paladin
     *4 Hunter
     *5 Druid
     *6 Warlock
     *7 Mage
     *8 Priest
     */
    public void addData(int clas, int coin){
        stats[clas][coin]++;
        if(coin==0)
            winCoin++;
        else if(coin==1)
            winNoCoin++;
        else if(coin==2)
            lossCoin++;
        else
            lossNoCoin++;
    }

    public int getData(int clas, int coin){
        return stats[clas][coin];
    }

    public int getWinCoin(){
        return winCoin;
    }
    public int getWinNoCoin(){
        return winNoCoin;
    }
    public int getLossCoin(){
        return lossCoin;
    }
    public int getLossNoCoin(){
        return lossNoCoin;
    }

}
```

I also have a UI class that implements a container and a table which are supposed to represent an array of Deck objects called *decks*.

When one deck is selected in the table, a form is filled out, and an *add data* button is clicked, I would like the selected deck to call its addData method. Does anyone have an idea of the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Hello Hearthsthone Fan,

do you already have a `UI` class you could show us? Do you already have a `Table`?

You can add a `ClickListener` on your `Table` to get the object of the `Deck` that was clicked and call `addData()` on it.